# What is pseudoscience? How is it different from non-science?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

*** I searched the question here in Stack Exchange and it wasn't reasonable

Comment: In philosophy of science this is called [the demarcation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demarcation_problem).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Definitional questions are off-topic on this site because they are already addressed by dictionaries and encyclopedias, e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscience) and [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pseudo-science/). We also discourage one-liners and take more contextualized and specific questions that come up after general reading.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudoscience is nonscience masquerading as science by its practitioners, who use scientific language and references to mathematics and fields of science in order to make their argument appear scientifically rigorous when it is not at all. As such it is deliberate fraud.

Nonscience makes no claim to scientific rigor and does not borrow scientific vocabulary in order to bolster its claims. A nonscience claim may still be fraudulent, of course, but not for the same reasons that all pseudoscientific claims are.